# Nodejs move files without deleting source directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to move files from one directory to another using the mv module. The problem is, once the files are moved, the source directory gets deleted. I dont want this, I want only the files that are moved to be deleted from the source directory. The source directory should remain (even if it is empty). Not sure how to do this with the mv module (or if there are any other options).

My code

```
var pathToPdf = path.join(__dirname, '../pathToPdf/');
```

`   var intermediate = path.join(__dirname, '../intermediate/');

```
 fs.readdir(pathToPdf, function(err, files) {
    if (err) return;

    files.forEach(function(file){

        mv(pathToPdf, intermediate, function(err) {
            if(err){
                console.log("oops!")
            }
        });
       ----move code ---
```

This code is moving the files to intermediate directory, but the pathToPdf  directory gets deleted, which I want to avoid. Please advise.

Comment: Please show the code for `mv()`.

Comment: var mv = require('mv');  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv

Comment: If the source and dest are on the same volume, then the source directory is just renamed to the destination location, thus the source is no longer present.  That's how `mv()` is written to work.  Also, why are you doing a `files.forEach()` and then not using the `file` you are iterating?  Your code looks wrong in that regard.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to resolve this. Since it is production code, I cannot paste in the whole code: but I got it to work as I wanted. Snippet below: files.forEach(function(file){
       
            mv(pathToPdf+file, intermediate+file, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    console.log("oops!")
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

```
 files.forEach(function(file){
           console.log(file)
            console.log("pathToPdf", pathToPdf+file)
            mv(pathToPdf+file, intermediate+file, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    console.log("oops!")
                }
            });
```